# Dynamically change the buttons of a jquery UI dialog box

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, modal-dialog

I've setup a confirmation dialog box to open with two buttons, one button executes an ajax request, the other closes a dialog box.

In case the response from the ajax request is false, i want to replace the two buttons.

If anyone could point me in the right direction, that would be appreciated.

This is what i have so far.

```
        $('body').on('click','.stream_mg_rmv',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var id = $(this).data('id');
        data = "<div><h4>This stream will be removed. This action cannot be undone. Are you sure?</h4></div>";
        $(data).dialog({
            buttons : {
                "Yes": function(){
                    if(delete_stream(id)){
                        $(this).dialog('close');
                        $('.stream_mg_modal').dialog('close');
                        get_streams();
                    } else {
                        $(this).prepend("AN ERROR OCCURED");
                    }
                },
                "Cancel":function(){
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: @NikolayErmakov the delete_stream function.

Comment: I wouldn't think the code you want to execute after your ajax runs works. Usually you will have to pass the callback to your ajax function, or move the code to the success method to do something after the ajax executes - since it is async.

Comment: the ajax works, depending on the data returned from the php script, the delete_stream returns true or false. On false, i need the buttons in the dialog box to change.

Comment: OK, then can you get hold of the buttons you have there by some selector and do whatever you want to do? I would add an id to your dialog: `<div id="dialog"><h4...` and then `$('#dialog').find('button').first()...` - this would be your first (Yes) button, and `$('#dialog').find('button').last()...` - this is the second button. Further depends on what you want to do with them.

Comment: Unfortunately, the buttons are being created outside the div.

Comment: It doesn't really matter. You could do `$('button').first()` to search whole page. Or you can look up in the chrome console what id or class they have and use those. You will need to get them somehow to change them.

Comment: Are you trying to change the function after the Dialog is open or at some other point? You can set the button options via the setter: http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-buttons I also do not see in your example where the failed ajax callback is run. Please expand on your example.